# Does the http server run on verticle and own event loop?

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-verticle

I am trying to understand https://vertx.io/ Verticle system and the event loop thread.

Consider the following code:

```
public class MyVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
  public void start() {
    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(req -> {
      req.response()
        .putHeader("content-type", "text/plain")
        .end("Hello from Vert.x!");
    }).listen(8080);
  }
}
```

The code above is going to create a new `Verticle(MyVerticle)` that also owns event loop thread.

When the `HTTP server` is created with `vertx.createHttpServer()`, does it spread a new **Verticle** for `HTTP server`? If correct, the `HTTP server` runs on own **Verticle** with event loop thread and two verticles are active.

Does the `MyVerticle` event loop thread:

```
requestHandler(req -> {
      req.response()
        .putHeader("content-type", "text/plain")
        .end("Hello from Vert.x!");
    }
```

execute the registered request handler? If yes, how does `MyVerticle` receive the events from `Http server` to run the handler when a request comes in?

The code above is not clear, how the two verticles communicate with each other. Would be great if someone could clarify it.

**Update**

I am trying to depict the scenario:

[image]

Assume, I deploy two instances of the same verticle, then each verticle will have its own event-loop and the HTTP server will be started twice.

When the user sends the first request, then it will process on the **Verticle 1** and the second request on the **Verticle 2**. When my assumption is correct, then the event loop threads are independent from each other. For me, that means for me it is no more single threaded.

For example:

```
public class MyVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
  
  final int state;

  public void start() {
    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(req -> {
      state = state + 1;
      req.response()
        .putHeader("content-type", "text/plain")
        .end("Hello from Vert.x!");
    }).listen(8080);
  }
}
```

When I change the state, then I have to sychronize between `Verticles`?

I pretty sure I am wrong, that means I not understand the concept of verticle yet.

Answer (score 5):

A verticle is a deployment unit associated with an event-loop. In your example the verticle controls the HTTP server (with `listen` and `close` methods). The HTTP server will uses the event-loop of the verticle that controls it.

When you deploy two instances of the same verticle (setting the deployment options to two), each verticle will have its own event-loop and the HTTP server will be started twice. The first verticle that binds the HTTP server triggers the server bind operation, the second verticle instead will register its request handler on the actual server started by the first verticle (since they use the same port). When the server accepts a new connection it will then load balance the connection on the two verticle instances that it is aware of. This is explained in this section of the documentation https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_server_sharing.

The recommended way for verticle to communicate is the event-bus. It provides a lighweight, fast and asynchronous message passing between verticles. A shared data structure can also be appropriate depending on the use case.

Comment: `the second verticle instead will register its request handler on the actual server started by the first verticle.`
The request handler on the second verticle will be executed on the first verticle event loop?

Comment: When I look the example on the page https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_server_sharing, it seems that the request handler runs on individual event loop. What for me is not clear is, when do the call on the second time, the second verticle receives the request but the request handler will run on the first verticle event loop?

Comment: the setup is actually symmetric, i.e the server has an acceptor channel that is independent of the event-loop of the verticles and a list of (event-loop associated with request handler). When the acceptor thread accepts a TCP connection, then it choses in this list (round-robin) an entry and call the request handler on its event loop.

Comment: @JulienViet If I understand correctly, thread-safe assumptions ("code like you are on a single thread") does not stand when you share servers, right? cause the same handlers are executed on multiple event-loops (= multiple threads)